# Could not find the Query for updating history in order history Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

its been a day i could not found where is the update query for updating the order history.
iam using chrome to see the post header and this is what if found.

```
http://localhost/shop1/upload/index.php?route=api/order/history&token=70ujvgRtR8KvyYEOJJkbTQyVYbv3eIZW&store_id=0&order_id=88
```

and this is the post data

```
order_status_id:5
notify:0
override:0
append:0
comment:
```

please help me to find it. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is located at

> catalog/controller/api/order.php

In this file search for '**history()**'. This method is what you are searching for.

The model is located at

> catalog/model/checkout/order.php

In this file search for '**addOrderHistory**' function. This function handles the queries.